# Javascript open popup window only once with closed event

Tags: javascript, popup

I have my code below with a function:

> If the popup window is closed, the alert box will show

But i want the the popup open only once. What i mean is if the popup is already exist, it will not create another popup window else it will just focus on the existed window.

```
function PopupCenter() {
    var win = window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo $bloglink; ?>', 'googl_e','width=800,height=400,status=0,toolbar=0,top=20,left=20');   
        var timer = setInterval(function() {   
                if(win.closed) {  
                clearInterval(timer);  
                alert("The video is ready to play.");
                $(".bg-lock").fadeOut();
                }
        }, 1000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a global var is exact thing you need.

**UPDATE**: I have some problems with global vars and window onbeforeunload event. Therefore, I use jquery for global var and use timer for checking

I assume that you use jquery (cause I see fadeOut method), so I use $.myWin as global variable.

```
function PopupCenter() {
   if ($.myWin == undefined) {
       $.myWin = window.open('https://google.com');
       var timer = setInterval(function() {
            if (($.myWin != undefined) && ($.myWin.closed)) {
               clearInterval(timer);  
               alert("The video is ready to play.");
               $(".bg-lock").fadeOut();
            }
          }, 1000);
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my lazy testing :D, I've updated my answer and tested it.